# Error in getting data from JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a JSON data as info.json.

```
[


    {"employee": {"name":"A", "salary": "324423"}},

        {"employee": {"name":"B", "salary": "43111"}},

        {"employee": {"name":"C", "salary": "43434"}},

        {"employee": {"name":"D", "salary": "120000"}},



]
```

and index.html as
    
        link
        linklinklink

```
    </body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var item,$emp=$('#emp') ;$aa=$('a') ;$sal=$('#salary');
    $.ajax({
    url:"info.json",
    success:function(data){
    item=data;
    }
           })

    $aa.click(function(){
      var index=$aa.index(this);
        var
        inf=item[index].employee;
            $sal.text(inf.salary);
        return false;
    })

    </script>
```

I just want to display name and salary of the employee on the click button from JSON DATA in index.html:

1. all simultaneously in 1 link
2. all by 4 seperately in 4 links

But getting error as:

[image].

I think it is simple but I am new to AJAX.
THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: I recommend to check the network developer tools of your browser to see if there is actually a response from server or if an error occurred.

Comment: Why do you enable click when you're not sure if you got results yet?

Comment: you need to parse your json using JSON.parse().

Comment: in line 26 (shown in the  image)

Comment: "  inf=item[index].employee;"

Comment: your JSON is not valid, remove the comma at the end of last line `{"employee": {"name":"D", "salary": "120000"}},`

Comment: item is supposed to be the arrays of employee in json? true?

Comment: @MaherFattouh yups right pointed

Comment: part 2:how can i display all json data simultaneously at one time in a single click??

Comment: see my answer, and please tell me what do you mean by "display" I will update my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First you need to make sure that the handler attached after the data came back from the server

   2. second you need to remove the (,) after the last JSON employee.

this is the JSON:-

```
[
{"employee": {"name":"A", "salary": "324423"}},

    {"employee": {"name":"B", "salary": "43111"}},

    {"employee": {"name":"C", "salary": "43434"}},

    {"employee": {"name":"D", "salary": "120000"}}
]
```

this is the code:-

```
 var item, $emp = $('#emp');
 $aa = $('a');
 $sal = $('#salary');
 $.ajax({
url: "info.json",
success: function(data) {
  //item = data;
  //handle click only after the data came back
  handleClick(data);
},
error:function(xhr,status,error){
  console.log(error);
}
 })
 var handleClick = function(item){
$aa.click(function() {
var index = $aa.index(this);
debugger;
if (item) {
  var
    inf = item[index].employee;
  $sal.text(inf.salary);
  $emp.text(inf.name);
}
return false;
  })
}
```

Here is a full [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rv7n7Dxb3XDh5WAg1CEM?p=preview)

Comment: yess but everytime it shows debugger is paused press F8.I am using chrome

Comment: i removed the debugger,
Added the name handling
check the demo

Comment: Ok that issue solved by removing debugger but why did we use it?

Comment: we use the debugger when we want to break the code at  a certain execution point of time to check our code state if it is as expected or not and figure out what we should change

Comment: please upvote if the answer is useful. happy it helped :)

Comment: Welcome any time bro.

Comment: my pleasure :).

Answer (score 1):

your JSON have an extra comma in the last line, remove it

your code is getting the json data but not parsing it, use this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "info.json",
    success: function(data) {
        item = JSON.parse(data);
    }
})
```

now you have you data in *item*

## Accessing your data:

Number of employees is `item.length`

1st employee name is `item[0].employee.name`

1st employee salary is `item[0].employee.salary`

2nd employee name is `item[1].employee.name`

2nd employee salary is `item[1].employee.salary`

and so on...

Comment: what does "JSON.parse(data)" mean and can't I simply use "data"

Comment: ajax will return data as a string, JSON.parse() will convert the data into a JSON object